# How to unlock row lock in mysql?

Tags: mysql

run following command;

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;
```

and then some of output;

> 7 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 25 row lock(s), undo log entries 1,
>   MYSQL thread id 30945,query id 1913360 localhost 127.0.0.1

How to unlock this locks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `FLUSH TABLE user`

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old question but without an answer. I got the same issue.

You can get the list of locked tables and rows with:

```
select * from performance_schema.data_locks;
```

You may need to unlock the table or row. MySQL locks are keeped by the running processes that generated them. So, the easy way to unlock the resources is to kill the threads that is keeping them locked. In your case the message states:

> 7 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 25 row lock(s), undo log entries 1, ***MYSQL thread id 30945***,query id 1913360 localhost 127.0.0.1

So you can remove the lock with:

```
kill 30945;
```

Hope that can help others that are looking for a quick way to fix this issue.